# Why additional anonymous created by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I created a volume named `testVol` using following command in docker:

`docker volume create testVol`

Then I tried running a container which uses the same volume.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    image: 'redis:latest'
    volumes:
      - testVol:/app/myfolder 

volumes:
  testVol:
    external: true
```

When I run `docker compose up` command, I can see that volume `testVol` is being attached to the container.  But along with it, i can see another anonymous volume created which is also attached to the same container.

[image]

What is this anonymous volume and why is it attached to the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`redis` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis)'s [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/f00ff0562e52e24f0cde26988628ad7de51fd8d8/7.2/Dockerfile), it contains the [line](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/f00ff0562e52e24f0cde26988628ad7de51fd8d8/7.2/Dockerfile#L113)

```
VOLUME /data
```

This tells Docker that there *always* must be some sort of volume mounted on `/data`.  If the operator doesn't explicitly mount something else there, Docker will create an anonymous volume and mount it.

In your setup you're mounting a volume on to `/app/myfolder` but nothing into `/data`, so the extra anonymous volume you're seeing is the volume Docker creates as a result of this `VOLUME` statement.